# Sublime build system to open file at local server address

Tags: bash, localhost, sublimetext3

For a website I'm developing with the help of a local server (running at `http://127.0.0.1:4000`), I try to write a build system for my Sublime Text project settings.

I have access to these variables (provided by Sublime Text):

- `$file`: Stores the absolute path to the file on disk:
  `C:\Users\User\dev\repos\base\dir\index.html`
- `$project_path`: Stores the location of the project file (usually the root of the project):
  `C:\Users\User\dev\repos\base`

Now what I want is the content of `$file` but instead of the `$project_path` I want `http://127.0.0.1:4000/~base`. For that task I tried the following with <s>Bash</s> cmd.exe:

```
CALL SET result=%file:%project_path%=http://127.0.0.1:4000\~base\% && echo %result%
```

This gives the desired result, however I can't seem to be able to apply it to the build system inside Sublime Text.

For now, I try to generate the correct address and output it via cmd.exe:

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Preview in browser",
            "selector": "text.html",
            "windows":
            {
                "shell": true,
                "cmd": [
                    "start", "cmd", "/k",
                    "CALL SET result=$file:$project_path=http://127.0.0.1:4000\\~base\\ && echo $result"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
> echo %result%
C:\Users\Philipp\dev\repos\base\dir\index.html:C:\Users\Philipp\dev\repos
\base=http://127.0.0.1:4000\~base\
```

So the substitution is not working when doing it in the build system, but in cmd.exe it does. I'm confused.

Comment: I don't think sublime can acces enviroment variables that way. If you want you can try to create a script that uses enviromental variables, and then in the sublime build call that script file.

Comment: @sergioFC Are you talking about file and project_path? These are maintained by Sublime. They're not environment variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've understood that they were enviroment variables because you used that variables in an echo instruction in bash. Are you using bash in windows through cygwin or mingw? If so when notice that when you use a command in a sublime build it is probably executed by windows console not by bash.

Comment: That actually came to mind while sleeping. I'm using Git Bash. So for Windows I'm looking for a different solution. I'll have a look. Thank you.

Comment: You should use replace in a variable (%).

Comment: @sergioFC Doing something like `CALL SET result=%file%` results in `%file%` when echoing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83469/discussion-between-sergiofc-and-kleinfreund).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Preview in browser",
            "selector": "text.html",
            "windows":
            {
                "shell_cmd": "CALL SET filePath=$file && CALL SET result=%filePath:$project_path=http://127.0.0.1:4000\\~base% && CALL C:/Progra~2/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %result%"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem was with windows replacement and variable asignation rather than with sublime builds.

As it has been said in chat and comments multiple CALL are necessary to use the real value variable because if not used windows will expand their value at parse time before the wanted value is asigned at execution time. In addition, `shell_cmd` can be used to run a unique command in shell.

Comment: When I replace `cmd` with `shell_cmd`, the build system stops working entirely.

Comment: Have you removed the cmd start /k and changed the array for a string?

Comment: Yes, I removed `"start", "cmd", "/c"` plus `"shell": true` and replaced `cmd` with `shell_cmd`.

Comment: And also removed the array and any trailing comma? It works for me, I use a simple build system created with Tools>BuildSystem>new BuildSystem, but I don't think that has to do with the problem. Any error or message on console?

Comment: Alright, turns out that I did not pay enough attention. I forgot to remove the `[]`. Thanks.